# How do I negotiate the opening of a larger than 16777215 sats channel on a Core Lightning node?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, ln-opening-channels, wumbo-channels

Core Lightning's describes a maximum amount that can be given as a parameter to [`lightning-cli fundchannel`](https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightning-fundchannel):

> The value cannot be less than the dust
> limit, currently set to 546, nor more than 16777215 satoshi (unless large
> channels were negotiated with the peer).

I want to open a private channel on my Core Lightning node.
How do I negotiate the opening of a larger channel than 16777215 sats?
I've [tried adding](https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightningd-config) `large-channels` to my `.lightning/bitcoin/config` but the `lightningd` failed to recognize this option and shutdown.